# Can Npgsql read from PostgreSQL columnar store?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, cstore-fdw

To use columnar store extension of PostgreSQL, foreign tables are created... Can Npgsql read from such tables? If yes, is it similar to reading from traditional tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.

No matter what the foreign data wrapper is, foreign tables behave just like normal PostgreSQL tables (at least when you read from them), so Npgsql won't even notice the difference.

Comment: I wanted to test that, but I didn't know how to install cstore_fdw on Windows! Nothing is said about that on GitHub. Any clue?

Comment: No. You best ask the maintainers if it is supported and how you should do it. Does the documentation contain no help?

Comment: They have an issue open about that with no final working answer...

Comment: That points in the direction that you maybe shouldn't use it.